# How to run godoc on some popular go repo?

Tags: go, documentation, godoc

New godoc have some nice features like list of callers etc. Anyway I have problems to run it, like:

```
➜  ~GOPATH git:(master) ✗ ls src/github.com/coreos/etcd/
CHANGELOG       DCO             Documentation   README.md       bench           build           contrib         error           fixtures        go_version.go   http            main.go         mod             scripts         store           tests
CONTRIBUTING.md Dockerfile      LICENSE         Vagrantfile     bin             config          discovery       etcd            foo             gopath          log             metrics         pkg             server          test.sh         third_party
➜  ~GOPATH git:(master) ✗ godoc github.com/coreos/etcd/discovery -http=:6060
No match found.
```

Does anyone can tell me how to run it on some popular go repos like etcd, which I am using above?

Comment: Did you set GOPATH? Looks ok to me.

Comment: Yep, I was running commands from GOPATH.

Comment: I see: `-http=:6060` doesn't seem to work when given a package. Either give a package name _or_ `-http=:6060`

Answer (score 1):

Godoc have two main functionnalities:

1. It displays the documentation for a package
2. It run a webserver that you can browse to see you local packages documentation

Here, you are trying to do both at the same time. Either remove the `-http=:6060` option to see the package documentation in the console, or remove the package path to run the webserver and search it in your browser.

Comment: I tried to run with http option, but what I am getting is just local version of go website....

Comment: But the package list should include your local packages.

Comment: Ok, so I am making something wrong since I have only std lib docs :(

Answer (score 0):

Godoc can either run documentation on your code to create output on the terminal (running godoc without -server or -http flags), or can be run as a server with -http/-server tags (and takes no other args). Can't be both at the same time.

If you don't see your code in packages, then you need to run `go install mypackage` For example if you have `github.com/coreos/etcd/discovery` cloned, then run `go install github.com/coreos/etcd/discovery` and it should appear in the go docs page run by `godoc -http=:port`

Just ran into this problem with my code and didn't see any other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
godoc -http=:6060 &
go get github.com/coreos/etcd/discovery
open http://localhost:6060/pkg/github.com/coreos/etcd/discovery
```

Comment: That's a great response, also, if you are unhappy about godoc's output, you can also use this one: https://github.com/dataf3l/go-doc